# Scroll in a navbar (Bootstrap 3), but keep the rest of the page still

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question regarding scrolling in a divider, but keeping the rest of the page still. Imagine this (since I just made this account and can't post any pictures.): The post is built out of 3 components:

- The navbar: Don't worry about this.
- The side menu: This is the part I want to scroll through, because it contains 40 elements that don't fit onto one single page.
- The content: I want this one to scroll as well, but I don't want it scroll at the same time as the side menu does.

Here is the code for the part I am talking about:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary fullheight" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
<div class="panel-heading">All branches</div>
<div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><input ng-model="search" class="centerhorizontal fullwidth" placeholder="Filter"></li>
            <hr>
            <li ng-repeat="branch in branches | filter: search"><a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{branch}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions whatsoever would be very useful!

Comment: could you mock it up in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I'll try to get it on JSFiddle. Didn't think about that yet.

Answer (score 0):

set a css rule of overflow-y: scroll on the div that you want to be scrollable
eg

```
#scrollable-area{
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 300px;
}
```

Heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WqtQ/) demonstrating this.